# list.remove(x): not in list even though it's a sample from that list

Tags: python

I had a lot of trouble to get my client server communication to work, but having finally achieved that I have one final small issue that I can't wrap my head around. I have a list of "stocks" on which I run a function that alters the value of said stocks in a certain range, and another one that "swaps" the original list, in other words, creates another list in the same style of the first one with the new values. After this I establish a connection between a client and a server process and pick a sample from the created list and after back and forth between the processes, there's an option on which if the client decides to accept that stock, the server should send it and then proceed to delete it. Everything in the code runs fine and the stock is sent, except for the fact that after sending the stock I can't delete it from my list in the server side, since I get an error `list.remove(x): x not in list`.

Server code (fixed version)

```
import pickle
import socket
import struct
from _thread import *
import random
from time import sleep

PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
ThreadCount = 0
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
records = [('Empresa:', 'Altri', 'Cotação:', 5.37), ('Empresa:', 'BCP', 'Cotação:', 0.13),
           ('Empresa:', 'Corticeira Amorim', 'Cotação:', 10.58), ('Empresa:', 'CTT', 'Cotação:', 5.12),
           ('Empresa:', 'EDP Renováveis', 'Cotação:', 20.64),
           ('Empresa:', 'EDP', 'Cotação:', 4.67), ('Empresa:', 'Galp', 'Cotação:', 8.70),
           ('Empresa:', 'Ibersol', 'Cotação:', 5.82), ('Empresa:', 'Jerónimo Martins', 'Cotação:', 16.83),
           ('Empresa:', 'Mota-Engil', 'Cotação:', 1.35),
           ('Empresa:', 'NOS', 'Cotação:', 3.03), ('Empresa:', 'Novabase', 'Cotação:', 4.60),
           ('Empresa:', 'PHAROL', 'Cotação:', 0.11), ('Empresa:', 'REN', 'Cotação:', 2.37),
           ('Empresa:', 'Semapa', 'Cotação:', 11.50), ('Empresa:', 'Sonae', 'Cotação:', 0.80),
           ('Empresa:', 'Sonac', 'Cotação:', 0.77), ('Empresa:', 'The Navigator Company', 'Cotação:', 2.96)]


def create_random_numbs(input_list):
    output_numbers = []
    for given_number in input_list:
        max = given_number * 1.25
        min = given_number * 0.75
        random_number = random.random()
        random_number_in_desired_range = min + (random_number * (max - min))
        output_numbers.append(random_number_in_desired_range)
    return output_numbers


def swap():
    input_numbers = [x[-1] for x in records]
    new_numbers_in_desired_range = create_random_numbs(input_numbers)
    new_records = []
    for item, new_number in zip(records, new_numbers_in_desired_range):
        item_as_list = list(item)
        item_as_list[-1] = new_number
        new_records.append(tuple(item_as_list))
    return new_records


output = swap()
swap()
print(output)

try:
    tcp.bind(ADDR)
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print("A aguardar ligação")
tcp.listen(10)


def handle_client(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode('Bem vindo à bolsa'))
    data = connection.recv(2048)
    while True:
        stock = random.sample(output, 1)
        order = pickle.dumps(stock)
        if data.decode('utf-8') == 'Quero trocar!':
            print("Pedido de troca recebido")
            size = len(order)
            size_in_4_bytes = struct.pack('I', size)
            connection.send(size_in_4_bytes)
            sleep(0.2)
            connection.send(order)
            sleep(0.2)
            reply = connection.recv(2048)
            if reply.decode('utf-8') == 'Y':
                size = len(order)
                size_in_4_bytes = struct.pack('I', size)
                connection.send(size_in_4_bytes)
                sleep(0.2)
                connection.send(order)
                sleep(0.2)
                output.remove(stock[0])
                print(f"A nova lista de ações é{output}")
                break
            elif reply.decode('utf-8') == 'N':
                print("Não quer comprar a ação.")
                break
    connection.close()


while True:
    Client, address = tcp.accept()
    print('Ligado a: ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]))
    start_new_thread(handle_client, (Client,))
    ThreadCount += 1
    print('Número de ligações: ' + str(ThreadCount))
tcp.close()
```

Comment: What if you loop more than once? That will happen for sure after you run this line.

Comment: so what you're saying is the loop continues? so I just tried to nest the if statements and add breaks but it still happens

Comment: true! I placed it in the while true loop, I hadn't tried this with multiple clients so hadn't noticed yet. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply that `random.sample()` always returns a list, even if you ask for just 1 element, so you are checking if `[x]` (and not `x`) is in `[x, y, z]`, which is obviously false. Replace it with `random.choice()`, which gives just one element, or change it to something like `output.remove(stock[0])`.

Answer (score -2):

First, check if object is in list:

if x in list:
list.remove(x)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't fix, since it doesn't consider stock existing inside the list in the first place, it just runs the code and ignores this